# Imported CSV data is not displayed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I watched a simple video tutorial on how to accomplish it, but nothing shows up on my project when I add the layer. Even if I try zoom to layer, the screen just shows blue. I'm not sure if it has something to do with my Excel, computer, or program. I really need help as I am new to QGIS.

(I just posted this, but it won't let me comment to people under that question any more)

I have a layer of google hybrid, but when I do add the new layer it is at the top and checked transparency and everything. Its just not accepting the data I entered into the excel spreadsheet is my guess to what the issue is.

1. I have the spreadsheet with the name, longitude, latitude.
2. Save as CSV
3. In QGIS go to `Layer > Add layer > Add Delimited Text Layer`
4. Upload the CSV Excel file
5. Add

Nothing shows even tho there is a line in the layers (bottom left) showing that "something" is there but if I choose "zoom to layer" it changes to a blue screen I have a

Base layer Google Maps hybrid, and an area of interest on Georgia
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are in `ESRI:54101`? Try to use `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic` as "Geometry CRS". And check the points are on the right location.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz for some reason I do not have that as an option to pic

Comment: @Blizz86 I have closed the other question per your request.

Comment: I also tried opening a brand new project and enter the cvs first. The points show up, but I am unable to add any other layers like a map.

Comment: Why are you using ESRI:54101?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz thank you so much. I have no clue how I ended up with the ESRI and once you said to type it in it shows up. So simple, yet I couldn't figure it out. Thank you, Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `EPSG:4326-WGS 84` as "Geometry CRS". And check the points are on the right location.

If `EPSG:4326` doesn't exist in the drop down list, then click the button near the drop down list and type `4326` to `Filter` box and select `WGS84  EPSG:4326` from the list.

[image]